# Android Developement - If-Then-Else Statement. Switching images

Tags: android

So What I would like to do here is that the starting image is assigned with Tag 0. When I run the method, I want the image to change to gallows1 and get a tag of "1". Then when its run again, I want it to keep gallows1 with a tag of 1, and then change it to gallows2, and reassign it.... Basically, I want 1 image to change to the next, and so forth as the method runs 6 times.

Here is what I have so far.

```
public void switchImage(View view) {
        ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        img.setTag("0");
        if (img.getTag() == "0") {
            img.setImageResource(R.drawable.gallows1);
            img.setTag("1");
        } else if (img.getTag() == "1") {
            img.setImageResource(R.drawable.gallows2);
            img.setTag("2");
        } else if (img.getTag() == "2") {
            img.setImageResource(R.drawable.gallows3);
            img.setTag("3");
        } else if (img.getTag() == "3") {
            img.setImageResource(R.drawable.gallows4);
            img.setTag("4");
        } else if (img.getTag() == "4") {
            img.setImageResource(R.drawable.gallows5);
            img.setTag("5");;
        } else if (img.getTag() == "5") {
            img.setImageResource(R.drawable.gallows6);
            img.setTag("6");
        } else if (img.getTag() == "6") {
            return;
        }
    }
```

The Game I am making is hangman, but instead of using graphics, I wanted to have a twist (its for a challenge proj) and have progressing images show up instead.

Comment: You should switch on view.getId()

Comment: so what help you need

Comment: Well its kind of hard to do that when Im in a time of crisis. Its due in the morning.

Comment: @colin350, I dont think that control ever cross after first if condition.

Answer (score 1):

Put this outside the method:

```
ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
img.setTag("0")
```

and remove `img.setTag("0"`) from inside the method

The way you have it now, `img.setTag("0"`) gets called everytime so it will always just hit the first if block. If you move it outside, then the first time the method is called, if block 1 will match, then the next time, if block 2, etc.

Comment: Would I move img.setTag("0") outside of the method? Like where should I move these two lines?

Comment: Please comment, I need this by tomorrow.

Comment: Put it somewhere that is called before switchImage is called for the first time. Or when you want to reset to the 1st image. You could put it in onCreate if you only want to cycle through the images once.